# When can I use newlines (line breaks) in my Powershell commands to improve readability

Tags: powershell, syntax, newline, code-formatting

How do I know when I can use a New Lines/Carriage returns in my Powershell scripts?  All of the search results when searching for this answer all point to the Output.  I don't care about the output in this case.  I am more interested in my ability to format my Powershell scripts for readability.

For Example.  Two versions of a Powershell command line below.  One works and one doesn't.  What the command does is unimportant in this case.  The point is I am needing to know when I'm allowed to create a new line and when I am not.

This command line Works as it's just one long single line:

```
& 'C:\Program Files\ArangoDB3 3.3.3\usr\bin\arangoimp.exe' --file 'C:\Program Files\ArangoDB3 3.3.3\usr\bin\tstImportJSON.json' --type json --collection users --progress true --overwrite true --server.username root --server.password password
```

This command line does NOT work due to the fact that there is a New Line in the middle of the script.

```
& 'C:\Program Files\ArangoDB3 3.3.3\usr\bin\arangoimp.exe' --file 
'C:\Program Files\ArangoDB3 3.3.3\usr\bin\tstImportJSON.json'
--type json --collection users --progress true --overwrite true
--server.username root --server.password password
```

In my case I'm just running different versions of the same command line after adding line breaks to see if they work or not.  I know that I can begin a New Line when using an IF statement.  I can also use New Lines when piping an object |.  My assumption is that somewhere there is a list of Powershell scripting rules.  I thought I had seen them somewhere once upon a time when I originally began getting into Powershell but no clue where it is now.

Comment: Actually it's not a script. It's only a command line. A simple command line is not allowed to have a line break. If you use a Powershell cmdlet like `Start-Process` you can use line breaks after commata, semikola, opening parenthesis or curly braces ... try it like this: `Start-Process -FilePath 'C:\Program Files\ArangoDB3 3.3.3\usr\bin\arangoimp.exe' -ArgumentList  "--file 'C:\Program Files\ArangoDB3 3.3.3\usr\bin\tstImportJSON.json'", "--type json", "--collection users", "--progress true", "--overwrite true", "--server.username root", "--server.password password"`

Comment: And of course you can use a line break after the pipe "|".

Comment: @Olaf: Using `\`` at the very end of the line _does_ allow you to spread a command across multiple lines. `Start-Process` serves a different purpose and is not a replacement for direct invocation of a console program.
_Splatting_ is the answer, if you want to avoid the tricky end-of-line `\`` syntax.

Comment: Good point.  What I posted was just a single command line that I am saving into a script which I am running via Task Scheduler.

Comment: Addendum: while array-based splatting is an option, @PetSerAl correctly points out that you can simply pass an array directly (when calling external programs).

Comment: @Olaf I've updated the original question by removing references to 'Script' and changed them to refer to a command line.  ty

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can **use `` ` `` as the line-continuation character<sup>[1]</sup>
at the *very end* of a line** (not even whitespace is allowed after it) in order to spread it across multiple lines.

Here's a simplified example:

```
& cmd.exe /c echo `
 hi `
 there
```

This is the equivalent of `& cmd.exe /c echo hi there` and yields `hi there`.

Note:

- **Since the `` ` `` character is both visually subtle and the syntax is easy to break by accidentally placing characters after it, consider using an *array* as an alternative - see below.**
- Individual commands must be on a single line and therefore need `` ` `` if you want to spread them across multiple lines, as shown above.
- However, **in a *pipeline* you may end the line with `|`** and continue on the next line, without needing the `` ` ``; e.g.:

  ```
    Get-Date | # Because the line ends with |, parsing continues on the next line.
      Select-Object Day
  ```

  - In **PowerShell [Core] v7+**, you may alternatively place the `|` at the start of the (very) *next* line:

    ```
        Get-Date  # PS v7+ only
        | Select-Object Day
    ```
- Additionally, **if individual *arguments* create a new parsing context in [*expression* mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing)** - such as an inherently multi-line capable `(...)` expression or a script block (`{...}`) passed to a cmdlet -  you're also free to spread the expression across multiple lines; e.g.:

  ```
    1, 2, 3 | ForEach-Object { # { starts a multiline-aware context
      $_ + 1
    }
  ```
- A ***hybrid* case** is an ***array-literal* argument**, which allows you to **break a command after an interior element's `,` separator**:

  ```
    Get-Date | Select-Object -Property Day,
                                       Year
  ```
- **Statements that *start* in expression mode *always* allow spreading across multiple line**s (though *embedded* command-mode statements are subject to the usual limitations):

  ```
    $foo =         # an assignment is parsed in expression mode
            'bar'
  ```

---

**Alternatively, consider the use of an *array***<sup>[2]</sup> to pass the arguments, which allows you to use multiline expression-mode syntax to define the arguments as individual array elements *beforehand*:

```
# Construct the array of arguments (using multiline expression syntax)...
$arguments = '/c',
             'echo',
             'hi there'

# ... and pass it to cmd.exe
& cmd.exe $arguments
```

Note: Array element `hi there` is passed as `"hi there"` by PowerShell: it employs automatic double-quoting to ensure that the argument is recognized as a *single* argument by the target program.

As an aside: **for calling *PowerShell* commands** (as opposed to *external programs*, as in the case at hand), consider constructing the arguments in a **[hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables)** for use with [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Splatting), where each entry key specifies a target parameter *name* and the corresponding value the parameter *value* (argument); e.g.:

```
# Define the hashtable representing the named arguments.
$argsHash = @{
  Filter = 'T*'
  File = $true
}
# Note the use of "@" instead of "$"
# Equivalent of:
#    Get-ChildItem -Filter T* -File
Get-ChildItem @argsHash
```

---

<sup>[1] `` ` `` is PowerShell's general-purpose escape character. Placed at the very end of a line, its function is subtly different: instead of *escaping* the newline that follows (which would mean *retaining* it as a literal), it effectively tells PowerShell to *remove* it and treat the next line as the continuation of the current one.</sup>

<sup>[2] An earlier form of this answer recommended array-based [*splatting*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting), before [PetSerAl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4003407/petseral) pointed out that for invoking *external programs* it's sufficient to use an array as-is.

While splatting can be used too, its semantics are subtly different if one of the array element is `--%`, the stop-parsing symbol (in short: only when splatting does `--%` have its special meaning).

Splatting is a useful technique when calling *PowerShell* commands, however, primarily in its *hash-table* form (see previous link).</sup>

Comment: Actually the backtick is not a line continuation charachter. It's an esacape charachter. And the "charachter" you escape is a line break it works as an line continuation charachter. But usually it's really bad style to use it this way and when you accidently have a space before your line break there's almost no way to see the failure.

Comment: @Olaf: Yes re escape character (that's why I said _as_ the line-continuation character). Its use _is_ special at the end of the line, however, because it doesn't _escape_ the newline, it _removes_ it (see my update).

Comment: @Olaf: Yes, the `\`` is visually subtle and easy to break - I've updated the answer to make it clearer that splatting is the better alternative. That doesn't make use of `\`` "really bad style", however - it is a legitimate part of the language.

Comment: You do not need splatting when passing array of strings to executables. `& cmd.exe $arguments` will work as well.

Comment: @mklement0  ;-)  ... as style is a matter of taste I'll keep my opinion about the use of backticks. But anyway it's technically possible to use it this way - so your answer is absolutely correct. I just wanted to recommend to not to use it if it's not really necessary.

Comment: As passing array do not require you to build variable beforehand you can as well write `cmd /c,<newline> echo,<newline> hi there`. But, of course, there is subtle case where splatting vs. passing array produce different results: `$a = '/c', 'echo', 'something', '--%', 'something else'` and `cmd $a` vs. `cmd @a`.

Comment: @PetSerAl: Good point about `--%`; the updated answer now recommends direct use of an array and talks about splatting - including  how it affects `--%` - in a footnote. Note that array-_literal_ use is not an option, however, at least in PowerShell _Core_: while the `,` chars. enable line continuation, they are _retained as part of the arguments_ (though that could be a bug, given that it doesn't happen in Windows PowerShell).

Comment: @mklement0 *Windows* PowerShell starting from v5 retain `,` if there are no space between comma and array element (array element can include comma): `cmd /c echo 1,2,3` and `cmd /c echo ( 1 ),( 2 ),( 3 )` vs. `cmd /c echo 1,2 ,3`. IMO it is implemented in very ugly way. I am not yet inspect any changes made in *Core* about that, but wrapping array literal with `(...)` or `@(...)` should likely disable that behavior: `cmd /c echo (1,2,3)` or `cmd /c echo @(1,2,3)`.

Answer (score 1):

Break down the script a little bit more for additional readability.

```
$1 = "--file 'C:\Program Files\ArangoDB3 3.3.3\usr\bin\tstImportJSON.json'"
$2 = "--type json"
$3 = "--collection users"
$4 = "--progress true"
$5 = "--overwrite true"
$6 = "--server.username root"
$7 = "--server.password password"
$Arguments = "$1 $2 $3 $4 $5 $6 $7"
& 'C:\Program Files\ArangoDB3 3.3.3\usr\bin\arangoimp.exe' $Arguments
```

Your output will look like this.

```
C:\Program Files\ArangoDB3 3.3.3\usr\bin\arangoimp.exe --file 'C:\Program Files\ArangoDB3 3.3.3\usr\bin\tstImportJSON.json' --type json --collection users --progress true --overwrite true --server.username root --server.password password
```

typically I would normally move an uglier looking beast like this into its own function.

Answer (score 1):

The standard way of formatting PowerShell arguments for readability is through [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-7.2), which consists of assigning a [hash table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables?view=powershell-7.2) to a named splatting variable carrying the options, and using the At symbol to dereference the arguments when needed.

Your specific example of running an application with arguments would be written like below, in [idiomatic PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-hashtable?view=powershell-7.2#splatting-hashtables-at-cmdlets).

```powershell
$arangoImpOptions = @{
    FilePath = "$env:ProgramFiles\ArangoDB3 3.3.3\usr\bin\arangoimp.exe"
    Arguments = @{
        file = "$env:ProgramFiles\ArangoDB3 3.3.3\usr\bin\tstImportJSON.json"
        type = 'json'
        collection = 'users'
        progress = 'true'
        overwrite = 'true'
        'server.username' = 'root'
        'server.password' = 'password'
    }.GetEnumerator().ForEach({ '--{0} "{1}"' -f @($_.Key, $_.Value) }) -join ' '
}
Start-Process @arangoImpOptions
```